# What is a good approach to allow users subscribe to keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, solr, redis

I have a rails application using Rails 4, PostgreSQL and hosted on Heroku.
The application revolves around the following models: User and Article.
A user can create articles. An article contains a title, description, location (latitude, longitude) and an image.

I would like to add a notification system that works as follows:

- A user can set-up a list of keywords that they wish to subscribe to.
- The user gets a notification if an article containing one of their keywords is added (in the title, but perhaps in description in time).

What is the best approach to implement this in a scalable way?

In its simplest form, I could create a model called Keyword that stores what keywords a user wants to be notified for.
Then in the create action for article, check to see if the title (or description) contains any of the saved keywords.

This sounds good but will probably fall over once any reasonable amount of users are added.

Obviously, a background task would do the trick but it still sounds wrong to do a basic string contains directly on the database.

Perhaps I could tokenize the title and description into an index and use a background process to handle the heavy lifting? I heard Postgres has some built in text search - could this work?
Could I use a Heroku add-on like Solr or Redis to handle all this or is it overkill? (Not having to pay for an add-on is an advantage).
Perhaps someone has a better implementation for the same functionality.

I know I can implement it quickly, I just want to be sure it implementation is up to scratch.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem. The slowest thing is to do a case insensitive search. What I would suggest to you is the following approach: let TID be the id of the row in which you store the title; then create a table which has one row for every word in your title in lowercase, with the corresponding TID. Than what you need is a join between the word and the keywords of the given user. You can speed up this query with hash indexes.

In my case, no one of the postgres text function was usable because they all have poor performance.

PS we implemented a full text search over about 60000 documents, so your case might be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mark91 - Am I correct in saying the schema would be an Article table (id, title, ...), a UserKeyword table (id, user_id, keyword) and as articles are created insert the words of the title into ArticleKeywords (id, article_id, keyword) ? Wouldn't the join on strings be pretty slow ? I would have to filter for stop words (a, the, it... etc) but it would work.

Comment: Yes you are right, something like this. The join (if everything is in lower or upper case) is much faster than using the `like` operator. Obviously, if you join on numbers you go faster, but now you are dealing with strings... Moreover some indexes can improve your performance in this way (I suggest hash indexes), whereas if you don't use joins indexes don't improve your performance (we tried come of them...). If you want you can give a try to this solution, so that you can estimate performances by yourself.

Comment: thanks. I will try to test this out and I'll let you know how it goes.